# Magento 2 REST API add product with category

Tags: magento2, api

I'm adding products with the following way to /rest/V1/products on Magento 2.

How can I add a product to a specific category? I'm using curl to post the data and can see the product added.

```
    ...

    $setHaders = array('Content-Type:application/json','Authorization:Bearer '.$adminToken);

    $productData = array(
        'sku'               => 'ZZZ simple 1  ' . uniqid(),
        'name'              => 'Simple Product ' . uniqid(),
        'visibility'        => 4, /*'catalog',*/
        'type_id'           => 'simple',
        'price'             => 99.95,
        'status'            => 1,
        'attribute_set_id'  => 4,
        'weight'            => 1,
        'custom_attributes' => array(
            array( 'attribute_code' => 'description', 'value' => 'Simple Description' ),
            array( 'attribute_code' => 'short_description', 'value' => 'Simple  Short Description' ),
            )
    );

    $productData = json_encode(array('product' => $productData));

    $requestURL = "http://192.168.1.225/rest/V1/products";


    $ch = curl_init();      
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $requestURL);

    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $productData);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $setHaders);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    if(curl_exec($ch)===false){
        echo "Curl error: " . curl_error($ch)."\n";
    }else{
        $response = curl_exec($ch) ?: "";
    }
    curl_close($ch);

    echo $response;

    ...
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

found the answer. Here it is for anyone else interested in this problem. A product can have one or multiple categories set as follows

```
    $productData = array(
        'sku'               => 'ZZ-TEST-' . uniqid(),
        'name'              => 'Simple Product ' . uniqid(),
        'visibility'        => 4, /*'catalog',*/
        'type_id'           => 'simple',
        'price'             => 99.95,
        'status'            => 1,
        'attribute_set_id'  => 4,
        'weight'            => 1,
        'custom_attributes' => array(
            array( 'attribute_code' => 'category_ids', 'value' => ["42","41","32"] ),
            array( 'attribute_code' => 'description', 'value' => 'Simple Description' ),
            array( 'attribute_code' => 'short_description', 'value' => 'Simple  Short Description' ),
            )
    );
```

Comment: how to add multiple products?

Comment: just make multiple REST calls

Comment: to add multiple products you can use the async bulk -> https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/rest/bulk-endpoints.html