# How to add product in Magento using REST API?

Tags: magento2, product, api, rest-api

I want to add a product using the REST API in Magento 2.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/103438/magento-2-rest-api-add-product-with-category

Comment: Thanks @PrashantValanda for your reference, I have gone through that but there I didn't get the steps to add products. Later I found and posted the answer here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this a good approach or have any other better solution please suggest me.

Currently, I am doing this :

Step1. Generate admin token:
I am using token for authorization, so create an admin token using this URL  Http://{baseurl}/rest/V1/integration/admin/token

Step2. Add product :
For adding the product, I am using following URL  http://magentogit.com/rest/V1/products/{SKU} , this is magento2 default API using put method.
For example:

```
http://baseurl/rest/V1/products/B201-SKU

 header:
   Content-Type - application/json
    Authorization - Bearer token

 Body:
{
  "product": {
    "sku": "B201-SKU",
    "name": "B202",
    "price": 30.00,
    "status": 1,
    "type_id": "simple",
    "attribute_set_id":4,
    "weight": 1
  }
}
```

Comment: how to add multiple products?

Comment: Let me check and will let you know shortly...

Comment: @MagePsycho I wrote my own endpoint to add multiple products by creating a custom extension. Sorry I can't paste complete code here.

Answer (score 4):

Example script that create downloadable product

```
<?php
$curl = curl_init();
$URL = "http://magento.dev";

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => $URL . "/rest/V1/integration/admin/token",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "{\"username\":\"admin\", \"password\":\"123123q\"}",
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "accept: application/json",
    "cache-control: no-cache",
    "content-type: application/json",
    "postman-token: 654c3084-0e0a-b3a1-043f-0960e695e520"
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

if ($err) {
  echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
  die();
} else {
  $key = $response;
}


$data = [
    "product"=> [
        "sku"=> "DownloadableProduct_18sdsd5",
        "name"=> "DownloadableProduct_185",
        "attribute_set_id"=> 4,
        "price"=> "1",
        "status"=> 1,
        "visibility"=> 4,
        "type_id"=> "downloadable",
        "extension_attributes"=> [
            "stock_item"=> [
                "manage_stock"=> 1,
                "is_in_stock"=> 1,
                "qty"=> "10"
            ],
            "downloadable_product_samples"=> [[
                "title"=> "sample1185869143",
                "sort_order"=> "0",
                "sample_type"=> "url",
                "sample_url"=> "http://example.com"
            ]],
            "downloadable_product_links"=> [[
                "title"=> "link-1-185862143",
                "sort_order"=> "1",
                "is_shareable"=> 0,
                "price"=> 2.43,
                "number_of_downloads"=> "2",
                "link_type"=> "url",
                "link_url"=> "http://example.com",
                "sample_type"=> "url",
                "sample_url"=> "http://example.com"
            ]]
        ],
        "custom_attributes"=> [[
            "attribute_code"=> "tax_class_id",
            "value"=> 2
        ], [
            "attribute_code"=> "quantity_and_stock_status",
            "value"=> [
                "qty"=> "10",
                "is_in_stock"=> 1
            ]
        ], [
            "attribute_code"=> "is_virtual",
            "value"=> 1
        ], [
            "attribute_code"=> "url_key",
            "value"=> "downloadableproduct-185892143"
        ], [
            "attribute_code"=> "links_title",
            "value"=> "Links title 185862143"
        ], [
            "attribute_code"=> "links_purchased_separately",
            "value"=> 1
        ], [
            "attribute_code"=> "samples_title",
            "value"=> "Samples185692143"
        ], [
            "attribute_code"=> "links_exist",
            "value"=> 1
        ]]
    ]
];


$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => $URL . "/rest/admin/V1/products/",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $data,
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "accept: application/json",
    "content-type: application/json",
    "authorization: Bearer " . $key,
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

if ($err) {
  echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {
  echo $response;
}
```

Comment: How to set product images?

Comment: @RakeshJesadiya Do you know how to set images? Please guide me. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Example script that create downloadable product

```
<?php
$curl = curl_init();
$URL = "http://magento.dev";

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => $URL . "/rest/V1/integration/admin/token",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => json_encode(["username"=>"admin", "password"=>"123123q"]),
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "accept: application/json",
    "cache-control: no-cache",
    "content-type: application/json",
    "postman-token: 654c3084-0e0a-b3a1-043f-0960e695e520"
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

if ($err) {
  echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
  die();
} else {
  $key = $response;
}


$data = [
    "product"=> [
        "sku"=> "DownloadableProduct_18sdsd5",
        "name"=> "DownloadableProduct_185",
        "attribute_set_id"=> 4,
        "price"=> "1",
        "status"=> 1,
        "visibility"=> 4,
        "type_id"=> "downloadable",
        "extension_attributes"=> [
            "stock_item"=> [
                "manage_stock"=> 1,
                "is_in_stock"=> 1,
                "qty"=> "10"
            ],
            "downloadable_product_samples"=> [[
                "title"=> "sample1185869143",
                "sort_order"=> "0",
                "sample_type"=> "url",
                "sample_url"=> "http://example.com"
            ]],
            "downloadable_product_links"=> [[
                "title"=> "link-1-185862143",
                "sort_order"=> "1",
                "is_shareable"=> 0,
                "price"=> 2.43,
                "number_of_downloads"=> "2",
                "link_type"=> "url",
                "link_url"=> "http://example.com",
                "sample_type"=> "url",
                "sample_url"=> "http://example.com"
            ]]
        ],
        "custom_attributes"=> [[
            "attribute_code"=> "tax_class_id",
            "value"=> 2
        ], [
            "attribute_code"=> "quantity_and_stock_status",
            "value"=> [
                "qty"=> "10",
                "is_in_stock"=> 1
            ]
        ], [
            "attribute_code"=> "is_virtual",
            "value"=> 1
        ], [
            "attribute_code"=> "url_key",
            "value"=> "downloadableproduct-185892143"
        ], [
            "attribute_code"=> "links_title",
            "value"=> "Links title 185862143"
        ], [
            "attribute_code"=> "links_purchased_separately",
            "value"=> 1
        ], [
            "attribute_code"=> "samples_title",
            "value"=> "Samples185692143"
        ], [
            "attribute_code"=> "links_exist",
            "value"=> 1
        ]]
    ]
];


$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => $URL . "/rest/admin/V1/products/",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => json_encode($data),
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "accept: application/json",
    "content-type: application/json",
    "authorization: Bearer " . $key,
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

if ($err) {
  echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {
  echo $response;
}
```

Comment: how to add multiple products?

Comment: Magento does not have batch update api. You can implement it by self or run code in loop.

Answer (score 0):

In order to create product in Magento 2. I assume that you use POSTMAN.

Use this endpoint to generate the token :
`http://mydomain.localhost/rest/V1/integration/admin/token`

Then when you have your token, you are ready to use this endpoint :
`http://mydomain.localhost/V1/products`

Here is how a payload looks like :

```
{
    "product": {
        "sku": "test",
        "name": "test",
        "attribute_set_id": 4, //chose the attribute set wanted
        "price": 50,
        "status": 1,
        "visibility": 1,
        "type_id": "simple",
        "weight": "0.5",
        "extension_attributes": {
            "category_links": [],
            "stock_item": {
                "qty": "1000",
                "is_in_stock": true,
                "use_config_max_sale_qty": true
            }
        },
        "custom_attributes": [
            {
                "attribute_code": "tax_class_id",
                "value": "2"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Now, If you want to add multiple products, you should use this endpoint :
`http://mydomain.localhost/rest/async/bulk/V1/products`

Here is the payload :

```
[
    {
        "product": {
            "sku": "product-a",
            "name": "product-a",
            "attribute_set_id": 4,
            "price": 3.99,
            "status": 1,
            "visibility": 1,
            "type_id": "simple",
            "weight": "0.5",
            "extension_attributes": {
                "category_links": [],
                "stock_item": {
                    "qty": "1000",
                    "is_in_stock": true,
                    "use_config_max_sale_qty": true
                }
            },
            "custom_attributes": [
                {
                    "attribute_code": "tax_class_id",
                    "value": "2"
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "product": {
            "sku": "product-b",
            "name": "product-b",
            "attribute_set_id": 4,
            "price": 3.99,
            "status": 1,
            "visibility": 1,
            "type_id": "simple",
            "weight": "0.5",
            "extension_attributes": {
                "category_links": [],
                "stock_item": {
                    "qty": "1000",
                    "is_in_stock": true,
                    "use_config_max_sale_qty": true
                }
            },
            "custom_attributes": [
                {
                    "attribute_code": "tax_class_id",
                    "value": "2"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
]
```

In order to use the bulk import, you would need to run the queue.
`bin/magento queue:consumers:start async.operations.all`

If you need to do it in code, basically you need to take the right interface, check the data that the interface needs to work and pass the data

Hope it helps.