# Magento 2 REST API Product Variants

Tags: rest-api

I am using the Magento 2 REST API. How do I create a variable product? Here is my goal:

T Shirt (Parent Item)
 - Small, Red 
 - Medium, Blue

I found this post, but I see no code to create product variants. I assume I must match to an existing attribute set.

[How to add product in Magento to using REST API?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/120570/how-to-add-product-in-magento-to-using-rest-api)