# How to add simple product in magento 2.2.5 programmatically?

Tags: magento2, product, simple-product, magento-2.2.5

I am new to Magento. I am trying to do things programmatically.

Is there another way to add simple product programmatically than [Programmatically create a simple product in magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/102922/programmatically-create-a-simple-product-in-magento-2) this.

I don't want to add a file in the root folder

Comment: From where you want to create?

Comment: @SukumarGorai is it a good way to add a file in the root? I have no idea what are the other ways to add product

Comment: No its not a good way. But I want to from where you want to upload simple products programmatically. Do you want specific url from where you can upload products?

Answer (score 0):

You can add products using

1. REST API, You can check [this thread](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/120570/how-to-add-product-in-magento-to-using-rest-api) if you are okay with using APIs
2. You can use CSV files to [upload products to Magento](https://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/system/data-csv.html)

Using REST API can be the alternative that you might be looking for rather than creating them using a script