# Magento 2 Unable to assign Product to category via API

Tags: magento2, api

There has been similar issues posted without an answer unfortunately but I am posting two ways in the API to set a category on a product both of which give different errors.

The first is using the categories repository (catalogCategoryLinkRepositoryV1)

example 
In body POST

```
{ 
    "productLink" :
    { 
        "sku" : "TEST_SKU5",  
        "position" : 0, 
        "categoryId" : "8",
        "extensionAttributes": {}

    }
}
```

Example Response :  This is the same response regardless of what category or product.

```
{
  "message": "Could not save product \"%1\" with position %2 to category %3",
  "parameters": [
    "144",
    0,
    "8"
  ]
}
```

The second is setting it under custom_attribute using the product repository in either new or update calls.  Both give the same result.

When setting the custom_attribute like below regardless of what sku and category I get an error.  If I leave out "category_ids" it works fine but defeats the purpose of using the API to manage product import and updates.

```
'custom_attributes' => array(
            array( 'attribute_code' => 'category_ids', 'value' => ["8"] ),
            array( 'attribute_code' => 'description', 'value' => 'Simple Description' ),
            array( 'attribute_code' => 'short_description', 'value' => 'Simple  Short Description' ),
            )
```

Error being the following, which is the only error I get regardless of what combination of sku and category even if the sku is not made yet and I am creating a new product..

```
"{\"message\":\"URL key for specified store already exists.\"}"
```

Comment: `URL key for specified store already exists` U can't use same Product/Category Name  http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/103438/magento-2-rest-api-add-product-with-category http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/rest/list.html

Comment: please add your full code for create api withing curl logic also.

Comment: I can add a new category and a new sku and I get the same error.

Comment: I've been following this issue for the same reason, may help: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/6671#issuecomment-251730504

Answer (score 1):

You have to check below code for set product in category with position,

```
   <?php            
        $url="http://127.0.0.1/magento2.1/"; //your custom site url...
        $token_url=$url."rest/V1/integration/admin/token";

        //Below 9 is category id....
        $product_url=$url. "rest/V1/categories/9/products"; 
        $username="admin";
        $password="admin123";
        //Authentication rest API magento2, get access token
        $ch = curl_init();
        $data = array("username" => $username, "password" => $password);
        $data_string = json_encode($data);

        $ch = curl_init($token_url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
            'Content-Type: application/json',
            'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string))
            );
        $token = curl_exec($ch);
        $adminToken=  json_decode($token);

        //9 is category id...
        $sampleProductData = array(
                    "sku" => "24-MB01",
                    "position" => 5,
                    "category_id" => "9",
                    "extension_attributes" => array()
        );
        $categoryData = json_encode(array('productLink' => $sampleProductData));

        $setHaders = array('Content-Type:application/json','Authorization:Bearer '.$adminToken);
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $product_url);
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $categoryData);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $setHaders);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        $response = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: hi rakesh, Please open once this url. and place order with cod. place order is not working. https://www.depoto.com its urgent to me. sorry for asking here

Comment: Look at your array for adding to category and then look at mine, they are almost identical.    categoryId and category_id as the key result in the same error.  Setting a different position doesn't change that.

Comment: You can just try with above solutions. I have test it.

Comment: This is the result of using your code :  "{"message":"Could not save product \"%1\" with position %2 to category %3","parameters":["237",5,"17"]}"

Comment: Have you checked category with id 9 exist or not for your admin?

Comment: Yes, I also changed it to try with other categories that do exist.

Comment: Have you changed sku for existing product?

Comment: I have checked above code for magento 2.1 with sample data category Training and product with 24-MB01

Comment: Yes, I even added a new sku that is not currently assigned to anything

Comment: I think you have to first create product and after you can using above api.

Comment: The product is created.

Comment: Now you can set those product attribute sku to above rest api call and check.

Comment: It was created before I tried it.   Come on now, don't assume I am this dense, lol.