# where should I get format of request body of REST api - Magento 2

Tags: magento2, rest-api, magento2.0.8

I'm trying to create **simple product** using magento REST api. I have tried this [link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/103455/36463), it works but I need to know full options of create product like **media gallery entries**,**product links**,...etc.

So I need to know what is full formats of request body of rest api for create product.

I'm looking similar to this [link](https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.4/reference/rest/process-definition/post-start-process-instance/#request-body) they can mention full options, it seems more friendly to interact with rest api.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get full request body for all Magento 2 rest api [Rest API](http://devdocs.magento.com/swagger/).

For simple product,

You can find **catalogProductRepositoryV1** hook to set simple product with images,custom attributes and related,upsell,crosssell or bundle option.

```
{
  "product": {
    "id": 0,
    "sku": "string",
    "name": "string",
    "attribute_set_id": 0,
    "price": 0,
    "status": 0,
    "visibility": 0,
    "type_id": "string",
    "created_at": "string",
    "updated_at": "string",
    "weight": 0,
    "extension_attributes": {
      "stock_item": {
        "item_id": 0,
        "product_id": 0,
        "stock_id": 0,
        "qty": 0,
        "is_in_stock": true,
        "is_qty_decimal": true,
        "show_default_notification_message": true,
        "use_config_min_qty": true,
        "min_qty": 0,
        "use_config_min_sale_qty": 0,
        "min_sale_qty": 0,
        "use_config_max_sale_qty": true,
        "max_sale_qty": 0,
        "use_config_backorders": true,
        "backorders": 0,
        "use_config_notify_stock_qty": true,
        "notify_stock_qty": 0,
        "use_config_qty_increments": true,
        "qty_increments": 0,
        "use_config_enable_qty_inc": true,
        "enable_qty_increments": true,
        "use_config_manage_stock": true,
        "manage_stock": true,
        "low_stock_date": "string",
        "is_decimal_divided": true,
        "stock_status_changed_auto": 0,
        "extension_attributes": {}
      },
      "bundle_product_options": [
        {
          "option_id": 0,
          "title": "string",
          "required": true,
          "type": "string",
          "position": 0,
          "sku": "string",
          "product_links": [
            {
              "id": "string",
              "sku": "string",
              "option_id": 0,
              "qty": 0,
              "position": 0,
              "is_default": true,
              "price": 0,
              "price_type": 0,
              "can_change_quantity": 0,
              "extension_attributes": {}
            }
          ],
          "extension_attributes": {}
        }
      ],
      "downloadable_product_links": [
        {
          "id": 0,
          "title": "string",
          "sort_order": 0,
          "is_shareable": 0,
          "price": 0,
          "number_of_downloads": 0,
          "link_type": "string",
          "link_file": "string",
          "link_file_content": {
            "file_data": "string",
            "name": "string",
            "extension_attributes": {}
          },
          "link_url": "string",
          "sample_type": "string",
          "sample_file": "string",
          "sample_file_content": {
            "file_data": "string",
            "name": "string",
            "extension_attributes": {}
          },
          "sample_url": "string",
          "extension_attributes": {}
        }
      ],
      "downloadable_product_samples": [
        {
          "id": 0,
          "title": "string",
          "sort_order": 0,
          "sample_type": "string",
          "sample_file": "string",
          "sample_file_content": {
            "file_data": "string",
            "name": "string",
            "extension_attributes": {}
          },
          "sample_url": "string",
          "extension_attributes": {}
        }
      ],
      "giftcard_amounts": [
        {
          "attribute_id": 0,
          "website_id": 0,
          "value": 0,
          "website_value": 0,
          "extension_attributes": {}
        }
      ],
      "configurable_product_options": [
        {
          "id": 0,
          "attribute_id": "string",
          "label": "string",
          "position": 0,
          "is_use_default": true,
          "values": [
            {
              "value_index": 0,
              "extension_attributes": {}
            }
          ],
          "extension_attributes": {},
          "product_id": 0
        }
      ],
      "configurable_product_links": [
        0
      ]
    },
    "product_links": [
      {
        "sku": "string",
        "link_type": "string",
        "linked_product_sku": "string",
        "linked_product_type": "string",
        "position": 0,
        "extension_attributes": {
          "qty": 0
        }
      }
    ],
    "options": [
      {
        "product_sku": "string",
        "option_id": 0,
        "title": "string",
        "type": "string",
        "sort_order": 0,
        "is_require": true,
        "price": 0,
        "price_type": "string",
        "sku": "string",
        "file_extension": "string",
        "max_characters": 0,
        "image_size_x": 0,
        "image_size_y": 0,
        "values": [
          {
            "title": "string",
            "sort_order": 0,
            "price": 0,
            "price_type": "string",
            "sku": "string",
            "option_type_id": 0
          }
        ],
        "extension_attributes": {}
      }
    ],
    "media_gallery_entries": [
      {
        "id": 0,
        "media_type": "string",
        "label": "string",
        "position": 0,
        "disabled": true,
        "types": [
          "string"
        ],
        "file": "string",
        "content": {
          "base64_encoded_data": "string",
          "type": "string",
          "name": "string"
        },
        "extension_attributes": {
          "video_content": {
            "media_type": "string",
            "video_provider": "string",
            "video_url": "string",
            "video_title": "string",
            "video_description": "string",
            "video_metadata": "string"
          }
        }
      }
    ],
    "tier_prices": [
      {
        "customer_group_id": 0,
        "qty": 0,
        "value": 0,
        "extension_attributes": {}
      }
    ],
    "custom_attributes": [
      {
        "attribute_code": "string",
        "value": "string"
      }
    ]
  },
  "saveOptions": true
}
```

Comment: really that links worked I have test with 10 pc all are complain about  "un responsive script" If I click any link nothing happen. Just saw title only :-)

Comment: oh my bad in chrome it works!