# How to add product with category name instead of category id in Magento using Rest API

Tags: category, api

I want to add product with category name instead of category id in Magento using Rest API.

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/103438/magento-2-rest-api-add-product-with-category

Comment: But this link category with id not category name

Comment: yes you create category that use that id

Comment: Yes but I want to add category with name

Comment: in api you add category with name?